# User Control Content Presenter binding issue

Tags: wpf, user-controls, contentpresenter

I am creating user control that will act as container for other control. I found code on StackOverflow and I created user control using that sample.
Here is code of my user control.

```
 <UserControl x:Class="ClassLibrary1.UserControl1"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClassLibrary1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
 <UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Custom Control Text Area 1" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"  />
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Custom Control Text Area 2" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

Code behind is as below

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
   public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
   {
       public UserControl1()
       {
          InitializeComponent();
       }
   }
}
```

}

Then I added this user control in other windows application project and added button in this user control so code looks like below

```
<StackPanel>
    <l:UserControl1>
        <StackPanel >
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Click"/>
            <Button Content="My Control's Content" IsEnabled="{Binding Isbuttonenable}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </l:UserControl1>

</StackPanel>
```

Now from my windows application project is working fine and Button control is able to Enable/Disable based on Isbuttonenable valye.

Now I updated User control and added ViewModel to user control. Here is code behind code of user control

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
   public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
   {
       UserControl1ViewModel model = new UserControl1ViewModel();
       public UserControl1()
       {
          InitializeComponent();
         this.DataContext = model;
       }
    }
}
```

Now when I use this updated control in my Windows Application project, data-biding is no longer working. Button is now no longer able to Enble/Disable based on Isbuttonenable value. What may be the solution for this. I want to keep ViewModel in my user control.

I tried lot of way and goggle lot but not able get the solution for this.

Comment: I experimented many aproaches and nothing worked. Then I found explanation: "TemplateBinding does not support two-way binding, only Binding does that. Even with your BindsTwoWayBeDefault option, it won't support two-way binding." See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913176/in-wpf-why-doesnt-templatebinding-work-where-binding-does

Answer (score 1):

When you're setting the `DataContext` of the UserControl from inside its own code that also affects bindings in any usages of that control. Originally your `<l:UserControl1>` usage had an inherited `DataContext` which presumably had an `Isbuttonenable` property, which you were seeing work. When you set a specific value for the `DataContext` it is the equivalent of changing your XAML to something like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <l:UserControl1 DataContext="{StaticResource MyUserControl1ViewModelInstance}">
        <StackPanel >
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Click"/>
            <Button Content="My Control's Content" IsEnabled="{Binding Isbuttonenable}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </l:UserControl1>

</StackPanel>
```

Looking at it this way it's pretty obvious that the binding is now going to be looking for an `Isbuttonenable` property on the `UserControl1ViewModel` object.

If you want to use an internal VM for your UserControl you'd be better off setting it as a new custom `DependencyProperty` on `UserControl1` and changing those bindings intended to use it to use `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` bindings to access that property specifically instead of the implicit `DataContext`.

I would also recommend rethinking your overall setup here. The prime advantage of a `UserControl` is that you can set a specific set of content in the `UserControl.xaml` file and manipulate that in the code-behind or just re-use it as-is. If you're going to be setting the `Content` externally like this, just use a base `ContentControl` instance and set up templates to customize it.