# WPF Event Not Raised when Dependency Property Changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls, dependency-properties

I have the following custom control based on the "heavy option" at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82464/How-to-Embed-Arbitrary-Content-in-a-WPF-Control) link:

```
public partial class SelectableContentControl : ContentControl
{
    public SelectableContentControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var isCheckedDesc = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(IsCheckedProperty, typeof(SelectableContentControl));
        isCheckedDesc.AddValueChanged(this, IsCheckedPropertyChanged);
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool),
          typeof(SelectableContentControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    private void IsCheckedPropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectable = Content as IAmSelectable;
        if (selectable != null) selectable.IsSelected = IsChecked;
    }
}
```

The style defined for the `SelectableContentControl` is as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls1:SelectableContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls1:SelectableContentControl}">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

...and my usage:

```
<controls:SelectableContentControl Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding Dummy}" IsChecked="{Binding Dummy.IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I want `IsCheckedPropertyChanged` to be called whenever the `IsChecked` value changes on the UI, but this isn't happening.  Anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TemplateBinding` works in a `OneWay` mode, meaning that the value is updated only in source-to-target direction (your control being the source, and the `CheckBox` inside the template the target). If you want the binding to work in `TwoWay` mode, you should use a normal `Binding` instead:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls1:SelectableContentControl}">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

Note that you don't need to specify `Mode=TwoWay` on the binding, because `CheckBox.IsChecked` property binds in two-way mode by default.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913176/in-wpf-why-doesnt-templatebinding-work-where-binding-does) for more detailed info.

Comment: Thanks, that was totally it.  The universe would have ended from heat death before I figured that out.