# Multi-stage binding from ViewModel to Custom-Control to controls on ControlTemplate not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a MVVM project with a View and a ViewModel in its `DataContext`.

In this project I have a class `ComboBoxCustom` which inherits from `ComboBox`. I define some additional functionality in my `ComboBoxCustom` class.

To this `ComboBoxCustom` class I assign a control template to define its appearance.

The (simplified) style defining the (simplified) control template looks like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type lib:ComboBoxCustom}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type lib:ComboBoxCustom}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding TextPropertyInComboBoxCustom}"/>

                    <ComboBox   DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}" 
                                ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}"
                                SelectedValuePath="{TemplateBinding SelectedValuePath}"
                                SelectedValue="{TemplateBinding SelectedValue}" 
                                SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Which resides in a `ResourceDictionary`. The real control template has some additional features which are left out since they are not relevant for the question.

I use this `ComboBoxCustom` control in my View using:

```
<lib:ComboBoxCustom ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollectionOfMyObjects}"
                     TextPropertyInComboBoxCustom="MyText"
                     DisplayMemberPath="MyDescription"
                     SelectedValuePath="MyValue"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyObject, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The view is ok, and all items get loaded in the ComboBox which I can select.

*The problem is that when I select a different item in the ComboBox, the property `SelectedMyObject` in my ViewModel does not get updated and consequently its setter is not called. Therefore, the (correct) information about the selected object is not available in my ViewModel.*

When I use `<ComboBox .../>` (without the `TextPropertyInComboBoxCustom` property) instead of `<lib:ComboBoxCustom .../>` everything works just fine but then I don't have the additional functionality defined in `ComboBoxMessage` which I need.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong and how to fix this issue so I can use `ComboBoxMessage` in my view? Preferably without breaking the MVVM pattern.

Thank you!

Comment: `{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}` is a OneWay binding (see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913176/in-wpf-why-doesnt-templatebinding-work-where-binding-does)). Change it to a binding with RelativeSource=TemplatedParent as suggested in the accepted answer

Comment: Thank you ASh, this was indeed the problem.

Comment: `:)`. What about `SelectedValue="{TemplateBinding SelectedValue}"` ? It is the same thing

Comment: I was wondering about that, can the binding to `SelectedValue` indeed be removed when `SelectedItem` is already bound?

Comment: `lib:ComboBoxCustom` is a general purpose control. Even if current use-case doesn't utilize SelectedValue property, in other situations it may come handy, so it is a reason to fix. On the other hand if "YAGNI" condition is true, remove SelectedValue for good. In any case it is better to do smth and not leave broken code around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanx to ASh's comment and information in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913176/in-wpf-why-doesnt-templatebinding-work-where-binding-does).

The problem is that the `TemplateBinding` is one way. Therefore, all information from the ViewModel can get into the controls in the template. But not the other way around.

The solution is to specify a normal binding as:

```
SelectedItem ="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Whichs does about the same as a `TemplateBinding` but is two way.

The control template has become:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type lib:ComboBoxCustom}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type lib:ComboBoxCustom}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding TextPropertyInComboBoxCustom}"/>

                    <ComboBox   DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}" 
                                ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}"
                                SelectedValuePath="{TemplateBinding SelectedValuePath}"
                                SelectedValue="{TemplateBinding SelectedValue}" 
                                SelectedItem ="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I am not sure about the `SelectedValue` property though. With the template like this, it works both when I use the `SelectedValue` property or the `SelectedItem` property.

The `Mode=TwoWay` option can be omitted in the view since the default binding mode for `SelectedItem` is already two way. The view line becomes:

```
<lib:ComboBoxCustom ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollectionOfMyObjects}"
                    TextPropertyInComboBoxCustom="MyText"
                    DisplayMemberPath="MyDescription"
                    SelectedValuePath="MyValue"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyObject}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind SelectedValue to the property in ViewModel

```
SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedMyObject, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

in your lib:ComboBoxCustom

Comment: Thanks, the problem persists. The `SelectedMyObject` is still not updated. This is because the template binding linking `ComboBox` in the ControlTemplate with `ComboBoxCustom` is OneWay. So the binding in the view in `ComboBoxCustom` will never get the change to relay any new information from the controls in the template.